# Removing duplicate TreeNodes

Tags: asp.net

Trying to remove duplicate treenodes when adding data from sql server. 
Data is added to tree ok but I can't seem to work out how to remove duplicates of the parent nodes.

```
public partial class SYS_Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{    
  public TreeNode testerr = new TreeNode();
  private List<string> _isdupe = new List<string>();
  private List<string> _dupe = new List<string>();

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    PopulateRootLevel();
    TV_Test.CollapseAll();
  }

  private void PopulateRootLevel()
  {
    const string connectionString = ("user=;" +
                  "password=;server =UsersSQL;" +
                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                  "database=System Details; " +
                  "connection timeout=30");
    // connects to sql DB

    // sql connection

    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    // sql queries to server

    SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Contract, [Server Name],[IP Address] FROM tblServers where Contract !='' AND [SERVER NAME] !='';", objConn);
    SqlCommand testquery = new SqlCommand("select s.contract ,COUNT(*)from [System Details].dbo.tblServers s where contract !='' group by Contract having count (*)>1 ;", objConn);


    // data adapater holds values of sql queries 


    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommand);


    // datatable to hold query data into nodes

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // data table populated  
    da.Fill(dt);


    //Calls popnodes method and includes dt + nodes for 

    PopulateNodes2(dt,TV_Test.Nodes);
  }

  //pop nodes method


  private void PopulateNodes2(DataTable dt, TreeNodeCollection nodes)
  {
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
      TV_Test.Nodes.Clear();
      TreeNode IP = new TreeNode();

      IP.Text = dr["IP Address"].ToString();

      // new instance of a treenode
      testerr = new TreeNode();
      testerr.Text = dr["Server Name"].ToString();

      testerr.ChildNodes.Add(IP);

      TreeNode parent = new TreeNode("Text1");
      parent.Text = "keyText1";

      parent.Text = (dr["Contract"]).ToString();
      _isdupe.Add(parent.Text);


      parent.ChildNodes.Add(testerr);

      nodes.Add(parent);
      string trued;
      trued = _isdupe.Distinct().ToString();

      if (trued.Equals(parent.Text))
      {
         TV_Test.Nodes.Remove(parent);
      }
      else
      {
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your algorithm is wrong, if you order your query you'll be able to fill the treeview with no duplicate directly.

Comment: provide your suggestion in comments